# Global PHP App Configuration Constants & "Includes"

Tags: php, constants, global

I am currently creating/re-building a fairly sizable PHP app/website that uses a few different API's and interfaces with a database. And so, I have to store API keys, App Keys and other such configuration data so they are all centrally accessible by all of the different files/pages.

Currently, I'm declaring variables in the global context and including them using require_once():

```
<?php //config.php
$API_KEY['somename']    =    "THIS_IS_MY_API_KEY";
$API_KEY['othername']   =    "ANOTHER_API_KEY";

$APP_ID['somename']     =    "APP_ID_HERE";
$APP_ID['othername']    =    "OTHER_APP_ID";

//So on and so forth, with all of the API data I need, like API URLs
//Also, I'm declaring things like this...

$__SITEWIDE_KILLSWITCH  =    false;
$__DEBUG_MODE           =    false;
$__DISPLAY_ERRORS       =    false;
?>
```

Then, In my other files, I reference these variables like this:

```
require_once('path/to/config.php');
```

Only downside is that if I have to reference them in functions, since they are not superglobals like the `$_GLOBALS` or `$_SESSION` variables, for instance, I have to do this:

```
function database_connect( ... ) {
    global $API_KEY, $APP_ID, $API_URL; //etc...
    ...
    ...
}
```

I want to avoiding passing in my API key's in through the function if I can. I am hoping to get some best practices on declaring site-wide global constants and maybe avoid calling the `global` keyword at the beginning of each function.

Should I be using `const` in my declarations? Any benefit in using the define() function?

Am I doing the right thing with `require_once()` or is there a better way to do this?

What do you all think? How should I be doing this?
Thanks!

Comment: Looks well thought out already. But you also seem to be aware that the last three should be global constants instead. As for the multiple config arrays, why not make it one big array or config object, and nest urls, apis, keys by app name? Or use a lookup function / utility class. Make the example less abstract for more concrete advise.